# What's chinese for "layer" in the Photoshop sense of the word?

Tags: translation

I want to say "Do not print this layer" in Chinese, as past of a photoshop file. How does one say "Layer" in the photoshop sense of the word in Chinese?

Google translate thinks the translation of "Do not print this layer" is: 不打印這一層

But I expect that there's a specific word used for photoshop that's not a literal translation of the English word "Layer".

Comment: '不打印這一層' not a complete phrase, seems like something missing there. '不打印這一層次' a better phrase for the native Mandarin speaker.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

层 is right. to be specified for layers in photoshop, it has the term 图层.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I think yours answer better, but I wonder why on [this article](http://www.chinatat.com/new/5_28/2009_8_20_xu054930454802890029000.shtml) on Chinatat.com and [this other one](http://www.phpv.net/html/35.html) at phpv.net, it seems 层 is enough?

Comment: Actually 层 already means layer. 图层 is an official term used in Photoshop's chinese version. literally 图层 == graphic layer

Comment: Uhm... I'll undelete my answer then, but yours seems more precise anyway. You have a +1 from me. :)

Comment: In graphics application domain, such as Photoshop, AutoCAD,etc. , the term is 图层. When both of the listener and speaker know what they are taliking about, it can simply be "层"

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the translations of many computer-related terms are shockingly literal from the American perspective.

Here's a whole list of all the Chinese menu items corresponding to layers and so on:
http://expl.cpst.net.cn/esoft/2011_08/314772867.html

Comment: In all of the entries of that list, layer is written as "图层", so Fivesheep's post actually answers the question. But that is a nice resource anyway... :)

Comment: I wouldn't doubt that it's sometimes shortened to just 层. You know, just for our convenience as non-native speakers. ;-)

Comment: I often laugh when learning new computer-science terms at my job. Or really almost all 专业词.

Answer (score 0):

The character used, according to my dictionary, seems to be 層 for traditional and 层 for simplified (céng).

Check [this article](http://www.chinatat.com/new/5_28/2009_8_20_xu054930454802890029000.shtml) on Chinatat.com, or [this other one](http://www.phpv.net/html/35.html) at phpv.net, I think they confirm that character.

Unfortunately, my level of Chinese doesn't allow me to formulate a sentence like the one you need. I'll ask some native speakers I know and get back at you.

Comment: After Photoshop (and its Chinese version) been used these many years in China, there is already and accepted translation, whether it is correct (redundant) or not. Even there exists a better one (it will be argued which is better), it will be hard to changed the accepted translation.